# Exception in plugin Android support "Icon cannot be found in"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I try to create new virtual device I get this exception:

> *Icon cannot be found in '/icons/versions/null_32.png', aClass='class icons.AndroidIcons'*

```
Icon cannot be found in '/icons/versions/null_32.png', aClass='class icons.AndroidIcons'
java.lang.Throwable
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:113)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader.getIcon(IconLoader.java:166)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ConfigureAvdOptionsStep$18.setValue(ConfigureAvdOptionsStep.java:769)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ConfigureAvdOptionsStep$18.setValue(ConfigureAvdOptionsStep.java:762)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.ScopedDataBinder.register(ScopedDataBinder.java:424)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ConfigureAvdOptionsStep.registerComponents(ConfigureAvdOptionsStep.java:519)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ConfigureAvdOptionsStep.init(ConfigureAvdOptionsStep.java:248)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardStep.onEnterStep(DynamicWizardStep.java:163)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ConfigureAvdOptionsStep.onEnterStep(ConfigureAvdOptionsStep.java:332)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.next(DynamicWizardPath.java:293)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.onPathStarted(DynamicWizardPath.java:160)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.showNextStep(DynamicWizard.java:356)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.doNextAction(DynamicWizard.java:339)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DialogWrapperHost$NextAction.doAction(DialogWrapperHost.java:301)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1719)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:787)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:463)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGetOk(DialogWrapper.java:1557)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1524)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1528)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.showAndGet(DynamicWizard.java:472)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.CreateAvdAction.actionPerformed(CreateAvdAction.java:43)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)



java.lang.Throwable
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:113)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader.getIcon(IconLoader.java:166)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ConfigureAvdOptionsStep$18.setValue(ConfigureAvdOptionsStep.java:769)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ConfigureAvdOptionsStep$18.setValue(ConfigureAvdOptionsStep.java:762)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.ScopedDataBinder.internalUpdateKey(ScopedDataBinder.java:167)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.ScopedDataBinder.invokeUpdate(ScopedDataBinder.java:147)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardStep.performUpdate(DynamicWizardStep.java:215)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardStep.access$000(DynamicWizardStep.java:51)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardStep$StepUpdate.run(DynamicWizardStep.java:396)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2057)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:266)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1$1.run(Alarm.java:321)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:719)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:787)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:463)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGetOk(DialogWrapper.java:1557)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1524)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1528)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.showAndGet(DynamicWizard.java:472)
at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.CreateAvdAction.actionPerformed(CreateAvdAction.java:43)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I'm trying to migrate to Android Studio but I've spent 2 or 3 days to fix the strange errors and bugs and still here I am! I'm really getting upset with AS

Comment: Mmm, I'd reinstall it completely. Did you try it?

Comment: Nope! after fixing some errors at this IDE I really don't want to reinstall but if i'll be sure it fix i'll do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem after I have updated buildToolsVersion to 22. I solve it by changing buildToolsVersion from "21.11.2" to "22" in build.gradle

Comment: If someone like me tried this and got confused when getting error when changing to build revision "22". You can open SDK Manager and check under the "Tools" category which Android SDK Build-tools version you have, preferably downloading the newest (currently 22.0.1) and type that in your build.gradle. Works excellent now!

Answer (score 1):

I created a fresh project using the Navigation Drawer activity. This gave me a PlaceholderFragment as an inner class, in my main activity source. I pulled the PlaceholderFragment into its own class. This caused the error described here.

I fixed it by doing:

- Build -> Rebuild Project (probably not necessary)
- Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
- File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Answer (score 0):

> Well, I did below to get away from this exception:

1- *Unistalled current version 1.1.0*

2- *installed older version of Android Studio*

3- *Updated the IDE to latest version!*

Answer (score 0):

Same here...go to build.gradle, i changed the following to 22

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "course.examples.helloandroid"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
....
}
```

and then sync.  It worked for me.
But I'm new to this so please take second opinion.
Cheers!